# How to translate the Home link when using Path Breadcrumb?

Tags: i18n-l10n, breadcrumbs

I am  using the [i18n](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) module in my site. When using the [Path Breadcrumb](https://www.drupal.org/project/path_breadcrumbs) module, I can manage the *Home* link text in Path Breadcrumbs settings, via `admin/structure/path-breadcrumbs/settings`

But there is nothing related to this within the page "Translate interface". Therefor it allways shows in the same language for all of my site languages.

How can I also translate this Home link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have the [Variable](https://www.drupal.org/project/variable) module installed/enabled. If you also have the 
[Path Breadcrumbs](https://www.drupal.org/project/path_breadcrumbs) module enabled (as seems the case in this question), then there will be an extra tab within admin/config/regional/i18n/variable of your site (tab title = Path Breadcrumbs).

Within that tab, there are over a dozens of options available for marking them as milti lingual variables. The "*Home link Title*" is one of them, and probably the one you need to enable here.